# Why does constant CLOCKS_PER_SEC not need to be namespaced with std:: but <ctime> clock() and clock_t do?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was trying out the `<ctime>` library to get a sense of type, `clock_t`, the `clock()` function and the constant, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. I noticed that I would have to namespace both `clock_t` and `clock()` with `std::` but not `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`. Why is that? How does `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` get to float on its own?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::clock_t start;
  double duration;

  start = std::clock();

  for (long int i = 0; i < 10000000000; i ++){
    // do something
  }

  duration = ( clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  std::cout << duration << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (along with most other names in all uppercase) is a preprocessor macro. Macros do not partake in the C++ namespace system as, if they did, code that uses them would not be compatible with C, which of course does not have namespaces.

Comment: thanks for moving the comment to an answer. Did you mean to type 'and if' instead of 'as if'?

Comment: "Did you mean to type 'and if' instead of 'as if'?" - no.